# Get timezone list in current system

Tags: java

How can I display a timezone list from our current system?
I have tried by using the code below, but it gives 585 records.
I want the timezones which are displayed in the current system timezone system.

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current system timezone system"? Do you want names instead of IDs?

Comment: Yes, I want to list of names from current system.

Comment: I want list of timezones. Yes I want it in Java

Answer (score 1):

This lists names of all available timezones:

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
for (String id : ids) {
    System.out.println( TimeZone.getTimeZone(id).getDisplayName() );
}
```

This lists name your system's timezone:

```
System.out.println( TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName() );
```

Comment: I want those timezones which displays in system timezone setting.

Comment: This displays current timezone.